# How to use android material design in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, material-design

I am using portable class in Xamarin.form. I want to use material design in my android and ios mobile app. But I am not able to get any good resources to use material design in xamarin.forms.

Comment: Xamarin forms supports material design on Android. It doesn't support it on iOS because its not an iOS thing, just an Android thing. I know Google have tried to push it on iOS including in their apps and by releasing an SDK for it, but it's unlikely Forms will ever support it on iOS.

Comment: Just search the web and you find a lot of resources. Here's a blog post from Xamarin about using Material Design for Android in Xamarin.Forms https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/

Answer (score 3):

There is a guide on adding AppCompat to your Xamarin.Forms apps [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/). This will help support material design themes.

1. Make sure you are using >= Xamarin.Forms 2.0
2. Make sure your Android project is compiling for Android 6.0 (API 23) or higher

[image]

3. Add new themes to support Material Design

**Resources/values/colors.xml**

```
<resources>
  <color name="primary">#2196F3</color>
  <color name="primaryDark">#1976D2</color>
  <color name="accent">#FFC107</color>
  <color name="window_background">#F5F5F5</color>
</resources>
```

**Resources/values/style.xml**

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Resources/values-v21/style.xml**

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <!--If you are using MasterDetailPage you will want to set these, else you can leave them out-->
    <!--<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
  </style>
</resources>
```

4. Update your MainActivity's `[Activity]` attribute

Add `Theme="@style/MyTheme"` to the attribute

5. Add toolbar and tab layouts

Create 2 new files in your `Resources/layout` directory.

**Resources/layout/tabs.axml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

**Resources/layout/toolbar.axml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

6. Finally, update the MainActivity again

   public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity  // was FormsApplicationActivity

Update the `OnCreate` method too:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  // set the layout resources first
  FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
  FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

  // then call base.OnCreate and the Xamarin.Forms methods
  base.OnCreate(bundle);
  Forms.Init(this, bundle);
  LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Comment: Thank you.This is mentioned in Xamarin documents. Any other resources apart from this like videos, blog or link will be helpful for me. Please share if you have.

Comment: This is how to do it, but latest versions of Xamarin Forms already use Material Design by default.